# Displaying Meteor.user()

Tags: javascript, meteor

I have this template:

```
<template name="index">
  {{#if currentUser}
    {{userid}}
  {{/if}}
</template>
```

What is the difference between

```
Template.index.helpers({
    userid: function() {
        return Meteor.user()._id;
    }
});
```

AND

```
Template.index.helpers({
    userid: Meteor.user()._id
});
```

The last one gives this error:
**Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property '_id' of undefined**

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The easiest thing to do is use `{{currentUser._id}}`

`Meteor.user()._id` is correct. The problem is when you load the page, initially the data is not available and `Meteor.user()` will be null until a DDP connection is established and your browser logs you in (this takes a few hundred milliseconds). `Meteor.user() && Meteor.user()._id` to correct this.

The difference between the two `Meteor.user()._id` is in one you are passing the first static value that loads when the template is loaded. It will stick to being that even if `Meteor.user()` changes, or you log out.

When you pass a `function` you tell the helper it can be recalculated and it will update if there are any reactive changed.

Comment: Yes, it is. I know that. But I want to understand the difference.

Comment: You edited your answer and commented in the 1 minute after I answered give me a few to adjust to your new question!

Comment: @torayeff I have updated the answer with the difference.

Comment: But
`Template.index.helpers({
    userid: Meteor.userId()
});`

seems to work

Comment: @VamsiV This is incorrect. I've mentioned it in the answer that it will *not always* be correct since it is not reactive. For example: If you log out while staying at the same template it will still say you are logged in. If you log in as someone else, it will say you're logged in as the first person. If you nest it in a method, it will always be correct if you change user or log out. If you pass `Meteor.userId()` directly you are passing the static value instead of the `function` which can be recalculated.

Comment: @Akshat what do you mean by "not always"? In which cases?

Comment: @torayeff It will be static. Meaning if you log out it will still give the _id of the user you were logged in before you were logged out. If you log in as someone else it will give you the wrong _id. It is not reactive. Also if you're logged in as someone else but the cookie expires and you load the page it will still say you are logged in as that person even though the cookie has expired. The basics of it is it is not reactive.

Comment: @Akshat yes it is. I have checked it and it display pervious user's id. Did not know about that. Is it written in docs?